# How can I speed up this pdf path integration calculation with a slow recursive function with 40^4 summed terms in each iteration?

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics, summation, recursion

I am writing a path integration code for a numerical approximation to a probability density function.

I essentially take some initial continuous probability density function p0 and then perform a numerical integration such that `p[x,1]=Sum[(delta/2)^4*p0*q[x]]` over `x` , where `x` is 4-dimensional with 40 quadrature points in every direction (40^4 points). Furthermore, q is the transition pdf dependent on conditional mean and variances at each quadrature point. Simply put, it is a function that requires replacement of a numerical value determined via a solution to a set of ODE's at each quadrature point.

Mathematically, I discretize $P(x,t)=\int_{R^4}{P(x_0,t_0)q(x,t|x_0,t_0)}dx_0 $, where x is a 4 dimensional vector of state variables.

The next iteration is then defined as `p[x,n]=Sum[(delta/2)^4p[x,n-1]*q[x]]/Integral[Sum[(delta/2)^4*p[x,n-1]*q[x]],x]` and so on. Note I need to normalize the function each time such that the integral is 1 and p does not blow up

My problem is then that, while I have made a somewhat working code, it is extremely slow. It in fact takes a day at least to obtain `p[x,10]`. It is likely that I will need `n>10000`. I have attached a code snippet.  Note that the problematic code starts only after `(*define path integration iteration*)`. Feel free to scroll to the end where it starts.

I appreciate any help!

Edit: I have updated my code to only use necessary memoization and pre-calculate the determinant and covariance in symbolic form. q is in fact also used every iteration. I have also realized that I do not care about `p[x1, x2, x3, x4, n]`, I only need `p[0, 0, x3_, 0, n_]`. I have also changed my paralleldo loop as it was previously looping in the wrong order. I have also looked into vectorizing my summations, but in each iteration, the covariance matrix is computed with 14 variables with 40^4 possible values for each. I am unable to think of an efficient way to do it.  Any ideas regarding vectorizing would be appreciated as well.

```
m11 = 1 + \[Mu]r*(1 + \[Eta]^2 + 2*\[Eta]*Cos[\[Phi][t]]);
m12 = \[Mu]r*\[Eta]*(\[Eta] + Cos[\[Phi][t]]);
m21 = m12;
m22 = \[Mu]r*\[Eta]^2;

(*mass, damping, stiffness matrix*)
M = {{m11, m12}, {m21, m22}};
Dm = {{2*xi, 0}, {0, 2*xie}};

K = {{1, 0}, {0, 0}};

(*external and nonlinear force*)

Force = {f + \[Mu]r*\[Eta]*(\[Phi]'[t]*2*\[Theta]'[t] + \[Phi]'[t]^2)*
     Sin[\[Phi][t]], -\[Mu]r*\[Eta]*\[Theta]'[t]^2*Sin[\[Phi][t]]};


eq = TrigExpand[
   M.{\[Theta]''[t], \[Phi]''[t]} + Dm.{\[Theta]'[t], \[Phi]'[t]} + 
    K.{\[Theta][t], \[Phi][t]} - Force];
(*solve for \[Theta]'' and \[Phi]''*)

sol = Flatten[Solve[eq == 0, {\[Theta]''[t], \[Phi]''[t]}]];

(*substitute the solution*)
\[Theta]Eq = 
  Expand[\[Theta]''[t] /. sol];
\[Phi]Eq = Expand[\[Phi]''[t] /. sol];

\[Theta]Eq = Expand[\[Theta]Eq];

\[Phi]Eq = Expand[\[Phi]Eq];


(*replace \[Theta][t]\[Rule]x[1] and so on*)

subs = {\[Theta][t] -> x[1], \[Phi][t] -> x[3], \[Theta]'[t] -> 
    x[2], \[Phi]'[t] -> x[4]};

(*individual diffusion coefficients*)

W1 = Coefficient[\[Theta]Eq, f] /. subs;
W2 = Coefficient[\[Phi]Eq, f] /. subs;
(*diffusion coefficients with noise intensity of 2d as a vector. Note \
d is a scaled noise intensity to be determined later*)
\
\[CapitalSigma] = {0, (W1 /. 
      x[3] -> x30) + (D[W1, x[3]] /. (x[3] -> x30))*(x[3])*Sqrt[2*d], 
   0, (W2 /. x[3] -> x30) + (D[W2, x[3]] /. (x[3] -> x30))*(x[3])*
     Sqrt[2*d]};

MatrixForm[%];
(*diffusion correlation matrix *)

Col = Outer[Times, \[CapitalSigma], \[CapitalSigma]];
% // MatrixForm;
(*individual drift coefficients*)

Driff1 = Collect[\[Theta]Eq /. f -> 0, \[Epsilon]];
Driff2 = Collect[\[Phi]Eq /. f -> 0, \[Epsilon]];

(*drift coefficients as a vector*)

A = {x[2], (Driff1 /. \[Phi][t] -> 
        x30) + (D[Driff1, \[Phi][t]] /. \[Phi][t] -> x30)*(x[3]), 
    x[4], (Driff2 /. \[Phi][t] -> 
        x30) + (D[Driff2, \[Phi][t]] /. \[Phi][t] -> x30)*(x[3])} /. 
   subs;
(*define two differential operators here*)
D1[f_, i_] := D[f, x[i]];
D2[f_, i_, j_] := D[f, {x[i], 1}, {x[j], 1}];

(*g: moment generating function*)

g[i_, j_, k_, n_] = x[4]^i*x[3]^{j - i}*x[2]^{k - j}*x[1]^{n - k};

(*generate a list of moments up to h-th order*)

G = Flatten[
   Table[g[i, j, k, n], {n, 1, 2}, {k, 0, n}, {j, 0, k}, {i, 0, j}]];


(*define two Gaussian closure functions*)

GClosure1[i_, j_, 
   k_] := \[CapitalEpsilon][i]*\[CapitalEpsilon][
     j*k] + \[CapitalEpsilon][j]*\[CapitalEpsilon][
     i*k] + \[CapitalEpsilon][k]*\[CapitalEpsilon][i*j] - 
   2*\[CapitalEpsilon][i]*\[CapitalEpsilon][j]*\[CapitalEpsilon][k];
GClosure2[i_, j_, k_, 
   l_] := \[CapitalEpsilon][i*j]*\[CapitalEpsilon][
     k*l] + \[CapitalEpsilon][i*k]*\[CapitalEpsilon][
     j*l] + \[CapitalEpsilon][i*l]*\[CapitalEpsilon][j*k] - 
   2*\[CapitalEpsilon][i]*\[CapitalEpsilon][j]*\[CapitalEpsilon][
     k]*\[CapitalEpsilon][l];


(*close 3rd and 4th order moments with 1st and 2nd moments using \
Gaussian closure*)

subs1 = Flatten[
   Table[x[i]*x[j]*x[k] -> GClosure1[x[i], x[j], x[k]], {i, 1, 4}, {j,
      1, 4}, {k, 1, 4}]];
subs2 = Flatten[
   Table[x[i]*x[j]*x[k]*x[l] -> GClosure2[x[i], x[j], x[k], x[l]], {i,
      1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}, {k, 1, 4}, {l, 1, 4}]];

(*SUBs applies in order subs2, subs1, and Table[G[[i]]\[Rule]\
\[CapitalEpsilon][G[[i]]],{i,Length[G],1,-1}]. The last substitutes \
\[CapitalEpsilon][G[[i]]] for G[[i]], where \[CapitalEpsilon][] \
denotes expected values*)
SUBs = 
 Join[subs2, subs1, 
  Table[G[[i]] -> \[CapitalEpsilon][G[[i]]], {i, Length[G], 1, -1}]]

(*moment equations. \[CapitalEpsilon][G[[i]]]\[Rule]y[i][t] \
substitutes state variables y[i][t] for \[CapitalEpsilon][G[[i]]]*)
\
MEQ = Flatten[
   Expand[Table[
      y[i]'[t] - Sum[D1[G[[i]], j]*A[[j]], {j, 1, 4}] - 
       1/2*Sum[D2[G[[i]], j, k]*Col[[j, k]], {j, 1, 4}, {k, 1, 
          4}], {i, 1, Length[G]}]] /. SUBs] /. 
  Table[\[CapitalEpsilon][G[[i]]] -> y[i][t], {i, 1, Length[G]}]
(*path integration*)

(*sub intervals*)
n = 20;
a = -1;
b = 1;
\[Delta] = (b - a)/n;
(*range of integration*)
rangeint = Range[a, b, (b - a)/n]

(*create quadrature points for path intgration*)

lpoints = 
  Table[rangeint[[i]] + (3 - Sqrt[3])/6*(b - a)/n, {i, 1, 
    Length[rangeint] - 1}];

rpoints = 
  Table[rangeint[[i + 1]] - (3 - Sqrt[3])/6*(b - a)/n, {i, 1, 
    Length[rangeint] - 1}];

qpoints = Sort[Join[lpoints, rpoints], Less];

(*Solve moment equations at each point*)

momvars = Table[y[i][t], {i, 1, 14}];

momeqns = Table[MEQ[[i]] == 0, {i, 1, Length[MEQ]}];

params = {\[Eta] -> .7, xi -> .02, xie -> .07, d -> .02, \[Mu]r -> .3};

initialcond = 
  Join[Table[
    y[i][0] == 
     y0[i], {i, {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}}], {y[3][
      0] == 0}];

parameters = 
  Join[Table[
    y0[i], {i, {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
      14}}], {x30}];

eqns1 = Join[momeqns /. params, initialcond];

ClearAll[tend]

tend = 1;

sol = ParametricNDSolve[eqns1, momvars, {t, 0, tend}, parameters];

(*Define initial moments for solving moment equtions*)

ics[i_, j_, l_] := 
  Table[G[[p]] /. {x[1] -> qpoints[[i]], x[2] -> qpoints[[j]], 
     x[3] -> 0, x[4] -> qpoints[[l]]}, {p, 1, Length[G]}];

minit = ParallelTable[
  Evaluate[
    y[z][t][ics[i, j, l][[1]], ics[i, j, l][[2]], ics[i, j, l][[4]], 
      ics[i, j, l][[5]], ics[i, j, l][[6]], ics[i, j, l][[7]], 
      ics[i, j, l][[8]], ics[i, j, l][[9]], ics[i, j, l][[10]], 
      ics[i, j, l][[11]], ics[i, j, l][[12]], ics[i, j, l][[13]], 
      ics[i, j, l][[14]], qpoints[[k]]] /. sol] /. t -> tend,
  {i, 1, Length[qpoints]},
  {j, 1, Length[qpoints]},
  {k, 1, Length[qpoints]},
  {l, 1, Length[qpoints]},
  {z, 1, Length[G]}
  ]

(*number of state variables=4*)
nss = 4;
xvars = {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]};
yvars = {y[1], y[2], y[3], y[4]};

(*initial pdf guess*)
p0 = 
 1/((2 Pi)^(nss/
         2)*\[Eta]1*\[Eta]2*\[Eta]3*\[Eta]4) Exp[-(y1)^2/(2 \
\[Eta]1^2) - (y2)^2/(2 \[Eta]2^2) - (y4)^2/\[Eta]4^2]*(Exp[-(y3 - \
\[Mu]3a)^2*(y3 - \[Mu]3b)^2/(2 \[Eta]3^2)]) /. {\[Eta]1 -> .1, \
\[Eta]2 -> .1, \[Eta]3 -> .1, \[Eta]4 -> .1, \[Mu]3a -> -.6, \[Mu]3b \
-> .6}

NIntegrate[p0, {y1, -1, 1}, {y2, -1, 1}, {y3, -1, 1}, {y4, -1, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 25]

p0 = p0/%


cov = (Outer[Times, xvars, xvars] - Outer[Times, yvars, yvars]) /. 
   Table[G[[i]] -> \[CapitalEpsilon][G[[i]]], {i, Length[G], 
     1, -1}] /. 
  Table[\[CapitalEpsilon][G[[i]]] -> y[i], {i, 1, Length[G]}]

(*define path integration iteration*)
invcov = Inverse[cov]
detcov = Det[cov]

sumq[zz_, i_, j_, k_, l_] := 
 Sum[(zz) /. Table[y[w] -> minit[[i, j, k, l, w]], {w, 1, 14}], {i, 1,
    Length[qpoints]}, {j, 1, Length[qpoints]}, {k, 1, 
   Length[qpoints]}, {l, 1, Length[qpoints]}]

q[y1_, y2_, y3_, y4_] = 
 Exp[-1/2*{{y1, y2, y3 - Indexed[qpoints, k], y4} - 
       yvars}.invcov.Transpose[{{y1, y2, y3 - Indexed[qpoints, k], 
         y4} - yvars}]]/((2*Pi)^(nss/2)*Sqrt[detcov])
p[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, 1] = (\[Delta]/2)^4*
  sumq[p0*q[x1, x2, x3, x4], i, j, k, l]

p[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, n_] := (\[Delta]/2)^4*
  sumq[p[x1, x2, x3, x4, n - 1]*q[x1, x2, x3, x4], i, j, k, 
     l]/(\[Delta]/2)^8/
   sumq[sumq[p[ii, jj, kk, ll, n - 1]*q[ii, jj, kk, ll]], ii, jj, kk, 
    ll]
ParallelDo[
 p[0, 0, x3, 0, n],
 {n, 2, 10},{x3, qpoints}
 ]
ClearAll[i]
ListPlot[Transpose[{qpoints, 
   Flatten[Table[p[0, 0, i, 0, 10], {i, qpoints}]]}]]
```

Comment: Scroll to the end to see the problematic code that is too slow

Comment: Can you make this into a minimal working example of your problem? What is it exactly what ends up being too slow? The summation itself or perhaps the subfunctions?

Comment: @CATrevillian I am not exactly sure to be honest. It is hard for me to determine which portion is slowing it down the most. Could it be due to ```/. Table[y[w] -> minit[[i, j, k, l, w]], {w, 1, 14}], {i, 
    1, Length[qpoints]}, {j, 1, Length[qpoints]}, {k, 1, 
    Length[qpoints]}, {l, 1, Length[qpoints]}]```  Where here I am substituting a new value for 14 different variables, 40^4 times, for one iteration?

Comment: I will note that the addition of ```/(\[Delta]/2)^8/
    sumq[sumq[p[ii, jj, kk, ll, n - 1]*q[ii, jj, kk, ll]], ii, jj, kk,
      ll]``` to ```p[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, n_] ```makes it much slower. Is there a way to speed up this portion at least?

Comment: You probably want to use Monte Carlo methods rather than an exhaustive method like this.

Comment: As CATrevillian mentions, it's kinda hard for an outsider to dive into your problem since there are so many definitions and parts to the code. That being said, I notice that you compute `Inverse[cov]` and `Det[cov]` for every `q`. The inverse is typically slow. Can you formulate it some other way?

Comment: You also seem to be using memoization, but are any of the values actually being reused?

Comment: @evanb for my system I have actually used a monte carlo method, but did not get stationary results. I am using this method as a new means of verification of the stationary pdf.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I indeed could probably get rid of memoization I guess. Would Inverse[cov] be making it that slow? Also, my code has been running for more than a day. Is there something obviously wrong in the last portion of my code that you notice? I think there might be Mathematica nuances that I still do not understand.  Thanks!

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer If it helps, the problematic part of my code is only in the last section where I start defining the iteration.

Comment: No, what I mean is that in general, finding a matrix inverse is an expensive operation, and you are doing it constantly. In many applications a `LinearSolve` would be better, but since the *meaning* behind the code is a little inaccessible, it's hard to know if it can be done without.

Comment: Memoization itself is fine unless you run out of RAM, but I was more thinking whether it is helping you at all here.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I now understand what you mean. I have edited my code to only calculate the inverse once. I have determined that my sumq function is what takes a very long time. Do you have any ideas or advice?

Comment: My system is chocking a bit on the `minit` calculation. How long does that take for you?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I did not time it and luckily only calculate it once. It does take probably on the order of 1 hour will 45 different kernels in parallel.

Comment: Haha, not gonna wait for it on my 2013 MacBook Pro then :P

Comment: So what is left to say, then, is that I think you are right when you say that the slowness is due to the replacement with `zz /. y[w] -> mint` part. Replacement is done at the top level in the MMA kernel and so is slower than stuff that could be done with pure numerics. You need to restructure this part somehow so that you can sum over the elements of a matrix that has machine precision numbers in it. In general your code is very "loopy" in the sense that you have indices on **everything**. (part1)

Comment: (part2) For speed it is always better to restructure the objects so that they become vectorized, and you can use vector operations like `Total` and `Inner` on purely numerical vectors/matrices.

Comment: I see, I will need to figure out the best way to do that. It seems tricky

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer when you say my code is "loopy", do you imply that there is a more efficient way than using indices?

Comment: Yes. Compare the time it takes to do `x=Range[10.^8];y=Table[Exp[x[[i]], {i, Length[x]}]` to `x=Range[10.^8]; y = Exp[x];` Loops like `Table`, `Sum`, `Do` etc. generally run in the top level of the kernel, unless they detect that the body of the loop construct can auto-compile or be automatically vectorized. This happens with some well-known functions but I guess not stuff like in your pretty involved case. Another example of "vectorization" is the difference between `x=Range[10.^8]; y=Sin[x]; Sum[x[[i]]*y[[i]], {i, Length[x]}];` and `x=Range[10^.8]; y=Sin[x]; x.y`.

Comment: Do you have any ideas as to how I can possibly turn my sums into vectorized equations?

Comment: No, because that requires some knowledge about the math that the code is trying to implement. But the fact that you had matrix operations like `Inverse` and `Det` in there makes me think that actually a lot of your code might be expressible in terms of matrix operations.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I am not sure there is an easy way. The math associated is basically the discrete version of integrating a probability density function multiplied by a short-time transition pdf over the whole domain composed of gaussian quadrature points. Each iteration corresponds to a time step.  Each summation is composed of 40^4 terms and there are 40^4 different inverse covariance matrices associated. That is what would be tricky in vectorization.

Comment: Of course, there must be an elegant way, but I feel that I might need to dive deeper into some advanced mathematical theorems.